# Can atexit() be called during a taskkill command?

Tags: c++, c, batch-file, taskkill, atexit

I am trying to use the atexit function to call a function but it doesn't seem to work if I use a batch file to do a taskkill command on the program. Is there some way to make this work?

Comment: What do you mean "during a taskkill command"?

Comment: Do you use `taskkill.exe /f`? Because that calls the `TerminateProcess` api on your process, which kills it immediately.

Comment: Anyway, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15277057/21567) should apply to your question as well.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way.

The entire purpose of `taskkill` is to *kill the process*. It will not shut down in any way gracefully.

A thing does not continue doing stuff after it's dead.

Comment: Agree, the atexit() function is used for a regular shutdown of a process.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had a feeling there wasn't a way to do that. Just wanted to make sure in case someone else had a way around it.

Comment: If someone had found a way round it, it would be a massive security problem!